# unable to wrap text in y axis title on R Shiny using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, word-wrap, shinydashboard

I'm trying to plot a graph in r shiny, where the values for x-axis and y-axis come from dropdown.

On y-axis, the title is very huge and i need to wrap it. But none of the wrap function is working.

**y-axis title = thistextisnumerator/thistextisdenominator, this needs to displayed, but i'm unable to wrap it**

```
**Possible y-axis titles:**

y-axis title = this text is very very long 
y-axis title = this text is very long (and very large) hence going outside the plot
```

code:

```
      ggplot(data=fin, aes(x = color_var, y = ratio,fill=color_var))+
      geom_boxplot()+
      geom_point(aes(text = paste0(paste0("number: ",number),
                                   paste0("<br>",isolate(input$Y),": ",round(ratio,2))))) +
      theme_grey(base_size=10)+
      ylim(min(fin$ratio),max(fin$ratio))+
      labs(title =paste0("Box Plot  ",' '),y=(paste0(isolate(input$X)," / ",isolate(input$Y))),x=x_value) +
      theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=1),axis.title.y = element_text(size=1)) +
      guides(fill=guide_legend(title=x_value_legend))
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide any data to help us help you so I'm building a dummy graph with the database *mtcars*. Let's see if this helps you:

```
#building dummy graph p
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=wt,y=mpg))+geom_point()
```

[image]

Now insofar as you seem to want your text in a mathematical annotation, I'd suggest to use the function `expression()`:

```
p + labs(y = expression(frac("thistextisnumerator", "thistextisdenominator")))
```

Which will result into the following graph:

[image]

If you do not want the line, you can use either one of the following codes:

```
p + labs(y = expression(atop("thistextisnumerator", "thistextisdenominator")))
p + labs(y = expression(over("thistextisnumerator", "thistextisdenominator")))
```

Or even easier:

```
p + labs(y = paste0("thistextisnumerator", "\n", "thistextisdenominator"))
```

Where `\n` is the character for line break.

[image]

Comment: Thanks it really helped. Sorry for not providing enough data. This is just one scenario, i will have other scenario where there is single text, and it very long, hence it should be generic where i can do wrapping for any long text. I have updated  with more examples

Comment: In that case, as I said in my answer, choose among the alternatives the one that adapts better to your problem. you can always use `expression()` for mathematical notation or `\n` to introduce line breaks wherever you want